# Repositories for Non-GPL Libraries for Linux?

Tags: linux

Do repositories exist for non-GPL-licensed code for Linux, especially Debian-based systems such as Ubuntu? If there are none, are there other ways to get pre-built versions of popular libraries, without the GPL-wrapping that they sometimes come with on Ubuntu?

Comment: What libraries are you looking for in particular?

Comment: You are confused. If it is not GPL'ed, then (to a first approximation) it is not open source, and hence not that likely to be on a *code repository*.

Comment: Your first approximation is approximately worthless.

Comment: @Suroot - One example is libpng (http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng_1.2.42-1ubuntu2.1/libpng12-0.copyright), which Debian has packaged, and, if I understand correctly, created a GPL-licensed shared object as a result.

Comment: @Suroot - Another example of GPL-packaged library is bz2, the copyright file for which you might find at /usr/share/doc/libbz2-1.0/copyright.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circumventing GPL Packaging of Non-Virally-Licensed Libraries for Debian or Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446539/circumventing-gpl-packaging-of-non-virally-licensed-libraries-for-debian-or-ubunt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely packaging a library does not necessarily change the license of the library itself (patches *may* change this, but do not force it). And since one never links against the package itself, the license of the packaging does not enforce restrictions on the license of any code using the library.

Comment: It is not "the license of the package", it is "the license of the *packaging*".

Comment: Ah, thanks, Ignacio. I deleted the comment to which Ignacio replied, which asked whether a package is the collection of files.

Comment: Ignacio, if you're interested, you might copy your reply to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446539/circumventing-gpl-packaging-of-non-virally-licensed-libraries-for-debian-or-ubunt, which I also asked. This question is a subset of that question. I realize now that having them both active wasn't a smart idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your example of bz2 is a bug in the packaging; the library is *not* under the GPL, and the maintainer probably meant that the build scripts added to create the package are GPL'd (which does not matter for the end-user). You should file a bug with the package maintainer to clarify the copyright file (I've [done this for you](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=619797) in this case)

That said, you won't find alternate repositories. There's no point - the packaging can't (or shouldn't) change the license of the original code, and so any alternate package would have to be under the same license. You could, in principle, create an alternate package where the package build scripts are under a different license; but this is also rather pointless as the package build script license does not affect the final end-user of the license at all.

Comment: You really did your homework on this one, Bryan. Thanks. Users should also read your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446539/circumventing-gpl-packaging-of-non-virally-licensed-libraries-for-debian-or-ubunt.